# Linux Server Performance

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 server running some services for me (such as Plex, nginx, Splunk, etc) and intermittently I've noticed that I'll have terrible performance for it. Web responses are slow, SSH is slow, but if I'm local on the machine it seems okay, I think. I'm really not sure what the issue is here, its happening over local and remote connections but when I have tested the network speeds they are 700mbps+. I'm not sure if this is related but when I boot my machine now, it also doesn't start up the network card and I have to tell it to bring it up. Checking the config it looks correct and I haven't found a solution for these. Is there anyway I can test to take a look at what is going on? Syslogs? I'm not even sure where to begin with this.

Comment: I'm not sure if you have already done so but I would definitely recommend asking the folks over at [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/).

Comment: Do you have a realech network card? These are bad news, particularly in servers.

Comment: Mine is the onboard one: Qualcomm Atheros AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet (rev c0)